# Mongo+PHP Querying nested (embedded) documents excluding fields +'Where' clause

Tags: php, mongodb, nested, php-mongodb

Trying to query nested documents(message collection) with embedded fields from an other collection(user)

here it is an example of the document i want to query:

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("52454de22660b239178b4567"),
  'from_uid' => array (
    'uid' => '5231817277758e660c7202d7',
    'uname' => 'franc',),
  'to_uid' => '5231817277758e660c7202d7',
  'object' => 'improving',
  'content' => 'mongo mega newbie bro',
  'datetime' => '2013-09-27 11:20:34',
)
```

I would (with just 1 query if it's possible) get and display the fallowing fields:

- uname      (value of the 'from_uid' sub-array)
- object
- content
- datetime

I have tryed in many ways without success, and starting to going crazy.. my last try was:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydb;

try{
  $array_qry = iterator_to_array($db->message->find(array("to_uid" => $this->uid_logged), array( "_id" => 0, "from_uid" => array('from_uid.uid' => 0, 'from_uid.uname' => 1), "to_uid" => 0, "object" => 1, "content" => 1,  "datetime" => 1)));
}catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
  echo "error message: ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
  echo "error code: ".$e->getCode()."<br/>";
}

foreach ($array_qry as $k => $v) {
  print_r($v);
}
```

the first array of the query define to select just the messages where the to_uid field is equal to the user_id of the user logged(sound obvious right?). Then there is the array and the sub-array(where probably is the error) for pick the fields.

I get this output, the warning is surely just a consequence of the wrong query that don't return any result:

```
error message: localhost:27017: Unsupported projection option: from_uid.uid
error code: 13097

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/nosql_portal/inc/classi/msg.class.php on line 128
```

Any help is appreciated